# Aggregation function in R

Tags: r, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a table that looks something like the following

```
Supplier        Reliability
A                 Pass
A                 Fail
A                 Fail
B                 Pass
B                 Pass
A                 Pass
```

I want to calculate the percentage of pass values for both suppliers. Something like a combination of group-by and case in SQL and I need to use the aggregation function. creating a custom function with the use of aggregation would also be acceptable.

I am totally stumped.
All I could come up with is

```
Supplier <- c('A','A','A','B','B','A')
Reliability<-c('Pass','Fail','Fail','Pass','Pass','Pass')
df<- data.frame(Supplier,Reliability)
agg<-aggregation(Reliability ~ GlassSupplier, data = df, FUN = length)
```

I want to create a table that looks like the following. Any help will be very greatly appreciated.

```
Supplier       Pass%
A               XX%
B               XX%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `dplyr` is available, you may try

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Supplier) %>%
  summarise(Pass = mean(Reliability == "Pass"))

  Supplier  Pass
  <chr>    <dbl>
1 A          0.5
2 B          1
```

For percentage format result, use `scales::percent`

```
df %>%
  group_by(Supplier) %>%
  summarise(Pass = scales::percent(mean(Reliability == "Pass")))

  Supplier Pass 
  <chr>    <chr>
1 A        50%  
2 B        100%
```